# Printing full calendar invitation?

Tags: macos, ical

I use OS X Mail and iCal connected to my company's MS Exchange server. Sometimes a co-worker sends a calendar invitation (using Outlook) with lots of agenda details in it. I'm trying to find a good way to print that.

iCal has an option to print the day's events in list format, but the output is in two columns and a few of the lines write over each other and are completely unreadable.

If I try to print the invitation as it came to me in Mail, the output has an iCal icon showing the attachment -- not the contents of the attachment.

So, short of copy/paste into TextEdit, Word, etc, is there a clean way to print this?

I asked this on superuser a few months ago and got no answers at all. Are the apple fanboys more active here?

Comment: I've had a question on Word 2011 for the Mac open on SU for some time with no answers. I think this site is a better place to ask Mac questions.

Comment: I've asked on SU and here on apple.stackexchange.com and there's no real answer to this. The best we can do is hope that this will be an option in 10.7

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Revisiting this over a year and a half later...

This has been improved in iCal in OS X Lion. On the print dialog, there's an option to print only the selected event. Also, the day option or list option will print the full contents without messing up the formatting or overwriting other lines.

In other ways iCal in Lion is worse, but it's definitely better for printing calendar entries.

Answer (score 0):

Better question: If the output from iCal was readable, would it be sufficient? The reason I ask, is because iCal word wraps within the two day columns, making the overlapping issue unusual. Perhaps the issue is with the iCal Application Support files or .plist

Comment: Not likely. I'm looking for full details of a calendar invitation. I have co-workers who sometimes include a 10 point agenda plus a couple paragraphs of explanatory information in the body of the invitation. It's *that* stuff that I want to print.

Answer (score 0):

Would going into iCal's day view, taking a screenshot & printing be a good solution for your needs?

Answer (score -1):

If we're talking about a single invite, and you wanted to go backwards in time and rely on paper (again) you could print the email invite. If you're wanting to print a collection of events you could make an applescript to do that quite easily. Drop the email onto your script have it open the attachment, screen shot the window of the appointment & overly that on top of the email. Screenshot the 2 together & print the png or drop it into a PDF to print it.

Comment: Nope. As stated in the question, printing the email only shows the icon. And, if I can't successfully print the full details of even one events, how will an applescript help me print multiple?